# What do we call 'Shakespearean trash-talk'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, literature, shakespeare, literary-english

A classic example:

In the opening scene of Richard II, Henry Bolingbroke and Mowbray seeks the adjudication of the king. They hurl accusations of treachery and cowardliness at each other. They engage in what we call in colloquial English 'trash-talk' without an actual fight of swords (they do later, but that is not the point). What formal/literary word can we use in describing that sort of 'trash-talk'?

Comment: It's not a single word, but I've heard such things called _verbal jousting_ before. Though it has a slightly nicer connotation than trash talking, I believe.

Comment: The words *trash* and *garbage* are seldom used in Britain either literally or metaphorically.

Comment: Again, "in colloquial English" ... you mean **today's** colloquial English.  To repeat myself from below, don't forget that Shakespeare is the towering figure in, well in all of civilisation really, the towering figure of **LANGUAGE GENERATION** -- he remains the most badass -ever "user of slang."

Comment: Hi WS2.  You raise an interesting issue.  100.0% of Britons would be aware that "trash-talk" is an Americanism meaning, the bad-mouthing that goes on between sportsmen - even though they, the Britons in question, don't use "trash".  Just as 100% of Britons would know that "sidewalk" or "trunk" [do I have that right?] are "Americanisms we Brits do not use.".  So the issue of whether "trash-talk" "is used" by Brits is tricky.   For example, 100.0% of Brits know what "bonjour" means ("it's something they say across the channel") .. is it "a British word"?  Is "trash-talk" in fact a "loan-word"?

Comment: I do not know the answers to these deep issues.

Comment: @JoeBlow: No, 100.0% of Britons would not be aware of that. Many - possibly most - would, but I know plenty of people (typically older, and who don't watch the right sort of TV etc) who would have no idea what the phrase meant.

Comment: Hi PS ... I'm pretty old, I find that hard to believe.  (Think how popular US movies and TV are.  Just one example -- every Briton knows what are "Seinfeld" or "The Simpson" for better or worse; carriers of such language.) But --- fair enough, I'll consider wot you say

Comment: @Joe Blow: Even as an American, I would not have thought that "trash-talking" is something that goes on between sportsmen, or even that sportsmen (or sportswomen, FTM) badmouth each other.  It seems to me that any sort of badmouthing rather disqualifies one from the sportsperson category.

Comment: It is a twist but ***swordplay*** is used figuratively for the battle of words. "*fig.* Spirited or skilful controversy or debate." - *OED*

Comment: For you lost Britons who have no idea what this "trash talking" is, it's _not_ talking rubbish. It's basically [sledging](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/sledging), though not limited to cricket. It is what the [Wealdstone Raider](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jnFAexQ3PM) became famous for, for example.

Comment: As a lifelong Briton, I’m familiar with the term _trash-talking_ but not _sledging_ — that’s new to me. But then again, I did grow up watching pro wrestling and not cricket.

Comment: @jamesqf Trash-talking is the most common form of psyching out/intimidating the opponent in competitive situations - sports, games, etc

Comment: @jamesqf the greatest exponents of trash talking are boxers, who I think are pretty much universally considered sportsmen, and wrestlers, who brand themselves "sports entertainers." Also regarding WS2's point, while I agree that it's an Americanism, I can think of no adequate equivalent in British English. As a result, I, for one, do use this expression.

Comment: @MartinBean If you've ever seen American pro wrestling, it's basically every word out of the wrestlers' mouths, and is very much part of the experience. In cricket it's strongly discouraged but happens anyway.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Which is a shame. It might liven cricket up a bit.

Comment: @asef Consider the word **taunt** which means _provoke or challenge (someone) with insulting or witty remarks_.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If it's mild, but witty, it's simply **word-play**.

If it's humorously argumentative, it's **repartee**.  or perhaps *verbal tennis* (I made that one up). They are trading **ripostes**.

if they try to outdo one another with their words, they are having a **battle of wits** or a **battle of words**.

if they insult one another, they are *trading barbs* or **trading insults**.
They are **sharp-tongued**.

If they are quick to come up with a **retort**, they could be said to have a **rapier wit**.

Comment: These are all excellent associated phrases. Note too that **you can and should definitely use 'trash talk'**. If your teacher or someone feels that is not dignified: tell them they are silly: Old Willy is the preeminent example in English culture of scandalously embracing and generating new ("slang" if you will) contemporaneous language of the day.

Comment: I think you mean [riposte](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/riposte), with an "e"?

Comment: +1 and you might add [*playing the dozens*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dozens) if the play were set in a modern urban style, a la Baz Luhrmann.

Comment: Related to the 'battle of wits' / 'trading insults': http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dozens , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extempo , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_rap

Comment: The OP noted the verbal sword play without swords, so I would tend towards those terms related to fencing, above: ripostes, with rapier wit.

Comment: 20 points!  nice

Comment: @psmears: thanks. "Ripost" is shown in some dictionaries (including the Scrabble dictionary) as an alternate spelling, but there are no hits  for "ripost" in Google ngram.

Comment: @JoeBlow, unfortunately, that only works if you are Shakespeare, or if plan to be congratulated 400 years from now.

Comment: `verbal tennis` – am I the only one who thinks of Henry V?

Answer (score 33):

How about [flyting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyting)?
It was a fairly commonly-practised activity in Shakespeare's time. Essentially it was the equivalent of a rap battle, in which it was not unusual for participants to insult the virility of their opponent, or suggest that their mothers were... promiscuous.

Comment: impressive!  nice

Comment: The best answer, in my opinion! Never heard of it before, but clearly that's what the Shakespeare characters were doing. And complete with mythology and illustration. Nice. +1

Comment: Most accurate answer, but very obscure. Depends on who the intended audience is.

Comment: I can't seem to find it on YouTube; despite being British, the TV series 'Time Team' is blocked in my country. They once did an episode that feature flyting, and it's worth a watch if you're able!

Answer (score 8):

As a formal/literary alternative to trash-talk I suggest :

[altercation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Altercation):

> - a heated or angry dispute; noisy argument or controversy.

or, with a stronger connotation, a [confrontation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confrontation):

> - a situation in which people, groups, etc., fight, oppose, or challenge each other in an angry way

(TFD)

Answer (score 5):

The Clown in [*As You Like It*](https://books.google.com/books?id=J4MVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA315&dq=%22upon+the+seventh+cause%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=elATVbTJF9K0ogSumoLIBg&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22upon%20the%20seventh%20cause%22&f=false) (act 5, scene 6) identifies seven forms of Shakespearean trash talk, each tied to a level of escalation in a quarrel:

> the *Retort courteous*,
>
> the *Quip modest*,
>
> the *Reply churlish*,
>
> the *Reproof valiant*,
>
> the *Countercheck quarrelsome*,
>
> the *Lye circumstantial*,
>
> and the *Lye direct*.

—all of which may be obviated by a well-timed *if*.

A footnote to the linked (1766) edition of *As You Like It* points out that Shakespeare took the *Lye circumstantial* (or *conditional*) and the *Lye direct* (or *certain*) directly from a book on disputation and dueling by Vincentio Saviello called *Of Honour and Honourable Quarrels* (1594)—"A discourse most necessary for all gentlemen that have in regard their honors, touching the giving and receiving the lye, whereupon the *Duello* and the *Combat* in divers forms doth ensue ; and many other inconveniences, for lack only of true knowledge of honor, and, the RIGHT UNDERSTANDING OF WORDS, which here is set down." Prescriptivism at its best!

Comment: Then perhaps I (an American) don't really understand what is meant by "trash-talk".  I would not think it necessarily had anything to do with a quarrel, but was more the sort of speech one thinks of as stereotypical rap: full of 'hos' and 'bitches', and with a strong element of brag.

Answer (score 4):

The term I would use is [**invective**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/invective), which refers specifically to this kind of verbal sparring and is [often used](http://complit.berkeley.edu/?page_id=3805) in Shakespearean scholarship.

Answer (score 3):

I struggle to offer a single formal/literary word for 'trash-talk' without degrading the formality slightly and falling back on my local dialect where use of the word "Banter" broadly describes an "exchange" (a suggestion in itself) often malicious, or taken as such (but then Scots are misunderstanding of each other).  All proper English though, I understand.   I'd go with:

To have an *exchange*.  To give *gyp*.  To *rip* and *deride*. *Banter* (sour sort).

To *square*

...not very Shakespearean is it?

Comment: Actually the last is literally Shakespearean: "And now they never meet in grove or green,
By fountain clear or spangled starlight sheen.
But they do square, that all their elves for fear
Creep into acorn cups and hide them there." - A Midsummer Night's Dream, Act2, Scene 1.

Answer (score 0):

> A graceful **taunt** is worth a thousand insults. *Louis Nizer*

You might want to consider [taunting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taunting).

[Twit](http://www.shakespeareswords.com/Glossary.aspx?Ref=twit&ID=6133) as a verb used occassionally by Shakespeare to describe these types of confrontation too.